# How to limit map display in Vue-Leaflet to specific boundary using leaflet plugin (without vue2 wrapper)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I am developing a simple Vue application to act as a repository for all things corona-virus in my country. I want to show a map using [Vue2-leaflet](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/) but i want only my country to appear such as this [example](http://aparshin.github.io/leaflet-boundary-canvas/examples/canvas-boundary-providers.html), its exactly what I want but its built using vanilla [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) using [leaflet-boundary-canvas](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas) which is a leaflet plugin.

I want to basically replicate this [example](http://aparshin.github.io/leaflet-boundary-canvas/examples/canvas-boundary-providers.html) but built using [vue2-leaflet](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/)

this is my [repo](https://github.com/Abel-Moremi/covid-info-bw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

- added `leaflet-boundary-canvas` package
- imported both `'leaflet'` and `'leaflet-boundary-canvas'` in `map.vue` and,

...because there is no `vue2-` wrapper for `leaflet-boundary-canvas` leaflet plugin, I used the plugin directly on the `mapObject`, in `mounted()` of `map.vue`:

```js
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-boundary-canvas';`
....

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const map = this.$refs.map.mapObject;
      window.L.TileLayer.boundaryCanvas(
        'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        { boundary: this.bwGeoJson.features[0] }
      ).addTo(map);
    })
  }
...
```

... where `this.$refs.map` is the `<l-map>`, and `this.bwGeoJson.features[0]` is the `GeoJSON.Polygon` of the boundary.

Here's the [PR on your repo](https://github.com/Abel-Moremi/covid-info-bw/pull/5), here's the [list of changes](https://github.com/Abel-Moremi/covid-info-bw/commit/901e4ddcece79f9dd40e68946ebd53082ec8cfce) and here's a screenshot with the result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Abel, I've pushed one more commit in which I added the geoJson for regions and some basic example of choropleth. You'll likely need to map real data onto it.